# Javascript RegExp - I'm getting cross-eyed

Tags: javascript, regex

This seems so simple, but I just can't get it right.

I'm trying to parse a parameter to a function, that is
(a) a filename with an embedded WIDTHxHEIGHT  --or --
(b) a filename without WIDTHxHEIGHT  --or--
(c) just a WIDTHxHEIGHT

It seems like I should be able to do this with a singe RegExp...

```
// PROCESS CORRECT SYNTAX
chopUp("abc300x150.jpg");   // should return:  abc, 300, 150, .jpg   - works
chopUp("abc.jpg");          // should return:  abc,    ,    , .jpg   - doesn't work
chopUp("300x150");          // should return:     , 300, 150,        - works

// PROCESS "IN-CORRECT" SYNTAX
chopUp("abc300x.jpg");      // should return:  abc300x,    ,    , .jpg   - doesn't work
chopUp("abcx150.jpg");      // should return:  abcx150,    ,    , .jpg   - doesn't work


function chopUp(str) {

  var m = str.match(  /(.*?)(?:(\d{2,5})x(\d{2,5})*)((?:\..{3,4})*)/  );

  if (m != null) {
    console.log("Prefix: " + m[1] + "\nWidth: " + m[2] + "\nHeight: " + m[3]  + "\ndotExt: " + m[4] + "\n");
  } else {
    console.log("m is null");
  }
  return(m);

} // function chopUp
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var m = str.match(  /^(.*?)(?:(\d{2,5})x(\d{2,5}))?(\..+?)$/  );
```

Comment: This worked except for the "300x150" case, but changing (\..+?) to ((?:\..+)?) fixed it. Thanks, my brain had turned to mush last night.